# Can I export schema of my realm file from iOS to Android

Tags: realm

I have realm OR mapping in Swift. Is it possible to export the same to Android without writing all the classes from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Realm Browser (https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx). You open a Realm file, and it has a function to generate model classes in Java and Objective C.